# Problems making global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and Jquery, but if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it as I've been struggling with this one for hours.

I have a function that's part of a larger plugin function (QueryLoader2 by Gaya if anyone's familiar). In the function I'm looking at, there's a part where it gets a percentage value of items that are being loaded in the page:

```
var completeImageLoading = function () {
    qLdone++;
    var percentage = (qLdone / qLimageCounter) * 100;

    if (qLoptions.percentage == true) {
        $(qLpercentage).text(Math.ceil(percentage) + "%");
    }

    if (qLdone == qLimageCounter) {
        destroyQueryLoader();
    }
}
```

The part "var percentage" is the part that I need to be gloabal, so the numeric percentage value can be used by another function completely outside of this one (in another Javascript file actually). I've tried removing the 'var' but that doesn't work.

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Outside your function put:

```
var percentage;
```

Inside your function put (no `var`):

```
percentage = (qLdone / qLimageCounter) * 100;
```

Basically, in JavaScript local variables declared in the same spot as a function may be used (both read and written) inside that function. A function using such local variables is called a *closure*.

Comment: Hi Phrogz, thanks for your quick response. I've just tried that - putting the 'var percentage;' at the top of the script, outside of the completeImageLoading function, and then removing the 'var' from inside the function, but now it comes back as 'undefined' when I run console.log. But when I run console.log within the completeImageLoading function, it gives me the numeric value okay. So it still isn't working :/

Comment: @RichDean You'll need to create a pared-down test case to share. This technique works perfectly well, so your implementation of it is not quite spot on. To help further we'll need to see your actual code that is failing. Try http://jsfiddle.net/ and edit your question with a pared-down example of minimal code showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var percentage;

var completeImageLoading = function () {
    qLdone++;
    percentage = (qLdone / qLimageCounter) * 100;

    if (qLoptions.percentage == true) {
        $(qLpercentage).text(Math.ceil(percentage) + "%");
    }

    if (qLdone == qLimageCounter) {
        destroyQueryLoader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi codetiger, yep just tried that and it's still not working:

     var percentage;

 var completeImageLoading = function () {
  qLdone++;
  percentage = (qLdone / qLimageCounter) * 100;
 
  if (qLoptions.percentage == true) {
   $(qLpercentage).text(Math.ceil(percentage) + "%");
  }
 
  if (qLdone == qLimageCounter) {
   destroyQueryLoader();
  }
 }
 
 console.log(percentage);

'console.log(percentage);' comes back with 'undefined', whereas if I move 'console.log(percentage);' within the completeImageLoading function, it works and gives me the numeric value I need. Only I need it outside!

Comment: Post your code which includes var diclaration an both functions. If used in right way as explained the code above should work perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you send more information about your script will be more easier to help you, but I'll try anyway.
First, you are doing something wrong for a Global variable return undefined.

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/WyShw/3/, the variable is defined (doesn't matter where), and is returning the value. Just verified if you are calling the function (completeImageLoading()) before call the variable, because in this case, you don't need to define the variable, it was defined when you call the function completeImageLoading(). We defined with a default value in case of we never call it in a function.